# No anda función de Javascript al querer implementar condicionales if y else if para ir sumando precios de productos

Tags: javascript, funciones, condiciones, else

En este código, el objetivo es ir sumando productos y hacer andar una condición u otra con los if y else if para que, dependiendo lo que vaya introduciendo el usuario, se cumpla o no tal condición y al final se sumen los precios que el usuario haya introducido
pero la función no anda... ¿estará mal planteada dicha función? la lógica habrá que reformularla o simplemente hay un error que no logro ver...

```
let producto1 = prompt('Agregar producto1');
let producto2 = prompt('agregar producto2');
let producto3 = prompt('agregar producto3');

let producto1Precio = 1000
let producto2Precio = 2500
let producto3Precio = 950

let totalCompra = 0

function compraSimulada(){
    if(producto1 == 'si'){
        totalCompra += producto1Precio
        alert('producto1 agregado ' + producto1Precio)
    }else if (producto1 == 'no') {
        alert('producto1 no agregado')
    }if (producto2 == 'si') {
        totalCompra += producto2Precio
        alert('producto2 agregado ' + producto2Precio)
    }else if (producto2 == 'no'){
        alert('producto2 no agregado')
    }if (producto3 == 'si') {
        totalCompra += producto3Precio
        alert('producto3 agregado ' + producto3Precio)
    }else if (producto3 == 'no') {
        alert('producto3 no agregado')
    }

    return alert('el total de tu compra es ' + '\n' + '$' + totalCompra)
}

compraSimulada();
```

Comment: Como Alex respondió (en realidad debió ser un comentario, pero eso es otro asunto), tu código funciona. Qué respuesta obtienes?

Comment: Tu código funciona. Deberías plantearte el caso de que el usuario no introduzca 'si' o 'no'

Comment: Al final el código funcionó pero creo que era un tema de caché...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues a mi me funciona, la lógica planteada realmente no es errónea. Prueba a refrescar la caché del navegador recargando con CTRL + F5...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si, pero si añado comentario no puedo poner foto... por eso puse como respuesta!

Comment: Disculpa, gracias!

Comment: Si lo ponías como comentario no te lo podría haber marcado como respuesta. XD